# I can't send email to groups now that I have added iCloud to Outlook; groups aren't found anymore

Tags: icloud, email

I had email groups set up in Microsoft Outlook. They were great. When I added iCloud, it moved all my contacts out of Outlook and put them in iCloud. But now when I want to send a group email, my email (still using Outlook) can't find my groups anymore.

I tried to make new groups in iCloud, and they seem to be there, but still are not found in Outlook. The old groups still show up in Contacts, but aren't apparently usable. I have them but can't get to them! Help!

Comment: How is your Outlook synced with iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

You might be facing the synchronization problem:

Microsoft chose not to support CalDav and CardDav in Outlook for Mac, unfortunately these are the services required by iCloud.

Although MS did add these to Outlook for Windows they did not add them to Outlook for Mac.

In short you can't subscribe (not sync) to iCloud from Outlook for Mac (although you can if you use Outlook for Windows)

Use Outlook, or use iCloud, not both.